# Remove specific lines from file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, unique

I have a directory that contains a large number of text files (typically named rt??????.MON).  Each file contains results in the format

```
#        HEADER INFO
#        ...
#
# --- TIME SERIES ---
#       TIME     Var1     Var 2     ...
#        [s]     [kg]     [kg]      ...
#          1       2        3       ...  
  0.0000E+00  1.0000E+00  1.0000E+00  ...
  6.4619E+00  2.0000E+00  2.0000E+00  ...
  6.4619E+00  2.5000E+00  2.5000E+00  ...
  8.9690E+00  3.0000E+00  3.0000E+00 ...
  ...
```

I'm trying to write a BASH script that will read down each file and remove lines with duplicate times (this is caused by rounding).  So for the example above the output would be

```
#        HEADER INFO
#        ...
#
# --- TIME SERIES ---
#       TIME     Var1     Var 2     ...
#        [s]     [kg]     [kg]      ...
#          1       2        3       ...  
  0.0000E+00  1.0000E+00  1.0000E+00  ...
  6.4619E+00  2.0000E+00  2.0000E+00  ...
  8.9690E+00  3.0000E+00  3.0000E+00 ...
```

Bit of a newbie at BASH so any pointers would be gratefully received!

Comment: What is the delimiter for the file?  Tab?

Comment: The files are space deliminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one-liner:

```
awk '$1!~/^#/&&$1 in a{next;}{a[$1]}1' file
```

Comment: Thanks. This one worked for me.  Though I haven't had chance to test the other solutions which could be as good.  I can see I'm going to have to spend sometime to learn awk.

Answer (score 1):

If the same times are adjacent (ie. in following lines) you can use just `uniq`. `uniq` has parameters to specify where to start comparing with the previous line, and how many chars you have to check (at least the GNU one). In the case, as it seems, that the numbers start and end at a fixed character you can write something like:

```
uniq --skip-chars=2 --check-chars=10 infile > outfile
```

`outfile` will hold different lines as of this set of characters.

As sudo_O comments, this solution may interfere with the header part of the file. I usually prefer having the files with just the data, and adding the header afterwards, or filtering the file before using `grep` or other tool to get just the lines of data, and then add the header part.

Comment: I almost like this answer.. however OP doesn't state duplicates are adjacent and this could remove lines in the header section for example, as OP omitted lines from the input.

Comment: Mmm... you're right about the header part. This is why it should be removed for processing by some kind of filtering (grep?) and added latter, for homogeneity and ease of processing. Also, as the numbers specify times (as per OP question), and are in increasing order, I think you can suppose they're adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is perfect for this:

```
$ awk '$1~/^[0-9].[0-9]{4}E[+-][0-9]{2}$/{if(!a[$1]++)print;next}1' file
#        HEADER INFO
#        ...
#
# --- TIME SERIES ---
#       TIME     Var1     Var 2     ...
#        [s]     [kg]     [kg]      ...
#          1       2        3       ...
  0.0000E+00  1.0000E+00  1.0000E+00  ...
  6.4619E+00  2.0000E+00  2.0000E+00  ...
  8.9690E+00  3.0000E+00  3.0000E+00 ...
  ...
```

Using a strict regexp comparison like this will ensure only the duplicates you want will be removed and the advantage of `awk` is the duplicate times don't have to be adjacent like with `uniq`.

Answer (score 0):

Another one you could try:

```
awk '/^#/ || !A[$1]++' file
```